# How do I ensure $page['content'] doesn't include a piece of content in a view on the page?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I have a block/view at the top of the front page that features three "featured" articles. For context, this view is achieved via a boolean checkbox field and not Nodequeue.

How do I make sure an article featured in this view is not duplicated in $page['content']? I only want an article to appear once on the front page, whether that's in the featured block or in the regular river of content.

Degree of difficulty: I would like to do this in code, without using Context or Display Suite or something similar.

Here's a mock, if that helps.

[image: Mock of Front Page]

Comment: What is generating the content of the page? Is that also a view?

Comment: It's not a view. Just the vanilla $page['content'] in the template files (page--front.tpl.php, page.tpl.php, etc.)

Comment: This is probably a promoted-to-frontpage node, have you tried to uncheck this option for the respective article-node?

Comment: @PanChrono That's actually a very simple, yet beautiful solution. The only downside I could see is when the node gets bumped out of the "featured" view, it will need to promoted to the front page to fall into the regular river of nodes.

Comment: Well, the features view should not have the promoted filter and you re done, i guess..

Comment: True, I can set them to be not promoted when featured, which would put them in the block, but not in $page['content'], which would work on the front page, but when another featured article makes the view, bumping the oldest out, I would have to cooks something up in Rules to then toggle promoted to yes so it shows up in the river. Make sense?